# Global const vs #define. Which is better from a security perspective?

Tags: c, macros, constants, buffer-overflow

### Using `#define`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define CONSTANT "Constant"

int main(void)
{
    char buf[32];
    strcpy(buf, CONSTANT);

    return 0;
}
```

### Using a Global `const`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char *constant = "Constant";

int main(void)
{
    char buf[32];
    strcpy(buf, constant);

    return 0;
}
```

Now suppose someone manages to hex edit the generated binary file. He/she could edit the global constant to cause a buffer overflow and hence execute arbitrary code.

My question is, is this sort of hex editing possible with `#define`s?

I haven't tried hex editing myself because I haven't the slightest idea how to decipher those hex values! I cannot find any reliable tutorials either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the name will be used more than once, you should probably use a global constant array:

```
const char constant[] = "Constant";
```

It occupies less space — the array name is a pointer but it isn't stored in memory.  By contrast, in the `const char *constant = "Constant";` version, you have both a stored pointer (that could be modified) and the string value.  If the name is only used once, you might decide to write the string directly as a literal in the code, or you can use the array or `#define` mechanism.

Even if you use the `#define`, the user would be able to 'hex edit' the generated binary file just the same as any of the other mechanisms.  There's no extra protection provided by the notation used.

Comment: +1 Thank you for teaching me that my constant uses more space! I didn't know that.

Answer (score 2):

Neither is more secure. At one point, both strings have to be stored in the executable file anyway.

Furthermore, if the user were to edit the binary file, I don't think they'd even bother to overflow your string at all - they'd just edit the binary code directly.

```
$ cat test.c
#include <stdio.h>

#if TEST == 0

#define str "Hello World\n"

int main() {
    puts(str);
    return 0;
}

#else

const char *str = "Hello World\n";

int main() {
    puts(str);
    return 0;
}

#endif
$ gcc test.c -Wall -DTEST=0 -o test0
$ gcc test.c -Wall -DTEST=1 -o test1
$ grep "Hello World" test0
Binary file test0 matches
$ grep "Hello World" test1
Binary file test1 matches
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But, wouldn't it be much harder to edit the binary code directly? I figured a buffer overflow would be much simpler.

Comment: Depending on what your program does and what the user is trying to bypass, it could be easier or harder. Piracy is usually one of the reasons and sometimes patching the binary file just simply involves replacing some bytes with nops.

Comment: Oh wow. Thanks for that example. I didn't expect that output.

Answer (score 1):

It is exactly the same. The only difference will be that using the #define the string will get an internal name automatically assigned by the compiler which is not accessible by the C program.

You can see it if you compile the program with the option -save-temps -fverbose-asm. This will leave the preprocessor result and the assembly program. You will see that in both cases the string will be declared, in one with the label of your `const *` in the other with a generated name.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the same thing, once you can edit your binary, these values can me modified.